# Why is my array being read as NULL in PostgreSQL, called from Java

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, multidimensional-array

This is the how I prepared my statement in Java to call the procedure createOrder()

```
PreparedStatement ps = Controller.getCon().prepareCall(QUERY);
        String username = "Hadi";
        int[] articles = new int[10];
        int[] quantity = new int[10];

        articles[0] = 1;
        articles[1] = 2;
        articles[2] = 3;
        articles[3] = 6;

        quantity[0] = 2;
        quantity[1] = 2;
        quantity[2] = 2;
        quantity[3] = 2;


        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        ps.setObject(3, articles);
        ps.setObject(4, quantity);

        ps.execute();
        ps.close();
```

The procedure is traverse the array and check if the product is available. If everything checks out, an order will be created and articles add to the order

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createOrder(
    username varchar(20),
    order_date Timestamp,
    articles integer ARRAY[10],
    quantity integer ARRAY[10]
    )
    language plpgsql
    as $$
    DECLARE
    temp_stock integer;
    temp_id integer;
    temp_order_id integer;
    BEGIN
    
FOR cn IN 0..9 LOOP
    IF (articles[cn] IS NULL OR articles[cn] = 0 ) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Im here at %', cn;
    END IF;
    SELECT stock into temp_stock temp_id FROM product WHERE id = articles[cn] FOR UPDATE;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Item not found, %', articles[cn][0];
        END IF;
        IF (temp_stock + quantity[cn] < 0) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '%, out of stock', articles[cn][0];
        END IF;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO an_order(a_username, is_confirmed, date) VALUES(username, false, order_date) RETURNING id into temp_order_id;

FOR cnn IN 0..9 LOOP
    IF (articles[cnn] IS NULL OR articles[cnn] = 0) THEN
        CONTINUE;
    END IF;
    
    INSERT INTO article VALUES(temp_order_id, articles[cnn], quantity[cnn]);
    
    UPDATE product
    SET stock = (stock + quantity[cnn])
    WHERE id = articles[cnn];
        

    
END LOOP;

commit;
END; $$
```

**This is what I read: "ERROR: Im here at 0"**
basically the articles[cn] is null (I checked that it is not equal to zero). I'm guessing the array is not being read properly.

**I would love to have them in a multi-deminsonal array**
articles[number of products in basket][product id, quantity]

Comment: Arrays in Postgres are 1 base indexing. Thus `articles[0]` does not exist and therefore it returns Null. Use `FOR cn IN 1..10 LOOP`.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! Sat for hours on it :(

Comment: Or just use `foreach` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY